# Hadoop namenode not starting on masternode?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing

> 15/09/10 14:45:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>          native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>          where applicable
>
> **Does not contain a valid host:port authority: :9000**
>
> Starting namenodes on []
>
> 192.168.0.81: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-spark-namenode-progen-System-Product-Name.out
>
> 192.168.0.81: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-spark-datanode-progen-System-Product-Name.out
>
> Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0] spark@0.0.0.0's password:
>
> 0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-spark-secondarynamenode-dell.out
>
> 15/09/10 14:45:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>          native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>          where applicable

**core-site.xml**

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://192.168.0.26:9000</value>
</property>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property> 
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
</property>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.tracer</name>
  <value>192.168.0.26:9001</value>
</property>
```

Comment: which distribution and vendor you are using for hadoop?

Comment: I'm using hadoop-2.6.0, and i figure out the solution & It's work for me just replace all the i.p's to there aliasing names.